# Encoding string and send it as url parameter?

Tags: php, jquery, post

Why this parameter does not pass:

```
file.php?t=%26quot%3B%26gt%3B%0A%09%09%09%26lt
```

Instead it gives:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /file.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an
ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

If you remove any of the characters it passes OK.
That string in parameter is generated in jquery.
How to encode this string and make it work?

EDIT: It was mod_security blocking set up by hosting provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a server configuration setting by your hosting provider - Passing that string as a `$_GET` parameter works for me.